# Pandas Dataframe - get Nth row before/after matched row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, match

How can I get the Nth row before/after matched row?

```
df_temp[df_temp.Date == pd.to_datetime(specific_date)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the first matched row with

```
idx = df_temp[df_temp.Date == pd.to_datetime(specific_date)].index[0]
```

And then you can obtain the nth row before (`idx-n`) or after (`idx+n`) with

```
df_temp.iloc[idx+n]
```

Edit based on @Ruli's comment:

In case we want to build this into a robust solution, we will of course have to check if the new index `idx+n` is in bounds.

We can do this by comparing against `0` and `len(df_temp)`.

```
new_idx = idx + n
if new_idx >= 0 and new_idx <= len(df_temp)-1:
    df_temp.iloc[new_idx]
else:
    print(f"Index {new_idx} is out of bounds for DataFrame of size {len(df_temp)}")
```

Comment: What if n=5 and idx is 2? or number of rows is 10, idx is 8 and n=5. This approach is fine but needs additional check to stay within bounds (negative indices can be fine, just from incorrect side of df, but too high will lead to crash)

Comment: I saw it as the user's duty to do this when I wrote the answer, but it should of course be done when providing a robust implementation. Thank you for the input, @Ruli.